# convert unstructured data to structured data?

Tags: email, parsing

How can I convert unstructured data into structured data?  For example email contacts, from an unstructured text, to a structured format.

Are there any algorithms to do this?

Comment: please provide some more details.. something like, sample input and sample output will be helpful in understanding your problem.
What and why do u want to convert, by email example do you mean getting all ids removing the domain part or something else, or you just want a CSV of the email ids. Put some more details please...

Comment: Please edit the description to explain what programming language you're intending to use, and (if so) tag your question with that language.

Comment: @mkamthan: basically getting the ids and storing in a email field in the database.

Comment: @bignose: i just like to know the idea not yet decided on the language to do the programming

Comment: do u mean a contact database?
A table having 2 (or more) columns:
Name | Email | ... 

i think you problem is of Parsing. Once we can have your sample input, we can think about the solution.

Answer (score 5):

There's no generic algorithm to "take unstructured data and convert it to structured data", no. It's highly dependent on what the possible range of input is, and what the desired structure is, and what conversions need to be applied, etc.

The **class of problem is called "parsing"**: you need to construct a parser for the specific inputs you expect, and use that parser to generate structure from what it discovers about the input you get.

Your programming language will likely have parsing libraries available to assist with constructing a specific parser.

Comment: can you tell we any 3rd party parsers that can do this?